# Is it at all possible to make a fixed body in css not scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

I have a matrix background thing that's fully functional but i'd only like to have my header move with the scroll, and every time I change the .content section to a different position it completely cancels the matrix (the matrix isn't actually a background it's more like an area behind everything else.

```css
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0px;
    background:#000;
}
.header-cont {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.header {
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    border:1px solid #0F0;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.content {
 overflow: hidden;
    width:960px;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #0F0;
    height: 4000px;
    margin: 70px auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Tech Time</title>
<link href="../CSS/something.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../CSS/canvas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href=".noscroll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0px;
    background:#000;
}
.header-cont {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.header {
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    border:1px solid #0F0;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.content {
 overflow: hidden;
    width:960px;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #0F0;
    height: 4000px;
    margin: 70px auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="header-cont">
    <div class="header"></div>
 
 <div class="content">
   <table width="960" border="1">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td width="338" height="180"><img src="file:///home/146971/Desktop/bigstock-128312288-1024x794.jpg" width="338" height="180" alt=""/></td>
         <td width="311" align="left" valign="top" style="color: #00FF00"><p style="font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-weight: bold;">Juicero - Silicon Valleys Failure</p>
           <p>By: <span style="font-style: italic">Alex Diaz</span> / <span style="font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif">April 24</span></p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif">Juice — yes, the beverage — has experienced a renaissance of late: Juice bars. Juice cleanses. Juices for enlightenment, juices for energy, juices that might just cure cancer...</p>
            <p style="font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: 10px;">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: 10px;">&nbsp; </p></td>
         <td width="289" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
       <tr>
         <td height="180"><img src="file:///home/146971/Desktop/watch.jpg" width="338" height="180" alt=""/></td>
         <td align="left" valign="top" style="color: #00FF00; font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-weight: bold;"><p>Fitbit's upcoming smartwatch has reportedly been a giant mess!</p>
           <p style="font-weight: normal">By: <span style="font-style: italic">Michael Esch</span> / May 2</p>
           <p style="font-weight: normal">&nbsp;</p>
           <p style="font-weight: normal">Yahoo Finance has nabbed a couple of photos. Reported to show Fitbit&rsquo;s upcoming smartwatch, along with a handful of reports that make the whole undertaking sound like one big fiasco...</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
          </tr>
       <tr>
         <td height="180"><img src="file:///home/146971/Desktop/jive.jpg" width="338" height="180" alt=""/></td>
         <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-weight: bold; color: #00FF00;"><p>Collaboration software company Jive to be aquired by Aurea for 462 million</p>
            <p style="font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;">By: <span style="font-style: italic">Ivan Diaz</span> / May 2</p>
            <p style="font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;"> Jive, a community collaboration software company that was one of the biggest Enterprise 2.0-era success stories, going public in 2011, announced today it had agreed to be acquired by ESW...</p></td>
          </tr>
       <tr>
         <td height="180">&nbsp;</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-weight: bold; color: #00FF00;">&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    </div>
     
<br><br><br>
<body>
<ul class="menu1">
 
  <li></li>
    <li><a href="HOME.html"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a>
     
        <ul>
         <li><a href="Tech.html" class="documents">Tech</a></li>
            <li><a href="Political.html" class="documents">World</a></li>
            <li><a href="Science.html" class="documents">Science</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>     
    <li><a href="#">Store</a>
 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="scom.html" class="documents">Computer</a></li>
            <li><a href="sgad.html" class="messages">Gadget</a></li>
            <li><a href="sran.html" class="signout">Random</a></li>
        </ul>
 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu2">Tutorials</a>
     
        <ul>
         <li><a href="java.html" class="Java">Java</a></li>
            <li><a href="css.html" class="Css">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="html.html" class="HTML">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript.html" class="HTML">JavaScript</a></li>
            <li><a href="elixer.html" class="HTML">Elixer</a></li>
            <li><a href="swift.html" class="HTML">Swift</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 
</ul>
</body>
<head>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/tech.js"></script>
</body>
</head>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit hard to understand so excuse me if that's not what you want, but here is a fiddle where you can see how to fix your header to the top/left, to prevent it to scroll with the content :

```
.header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x6gtb8rk/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean here, but if what you're going for is fixed header that stays at the top of the page on scroll then you should try this.

```
.header {
height:50px;
background:#000;
border:1px solid #0F0;
width:960px;
position: fixed;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top:0;
```

}

tested it out on codepen stays fixed and centered at the top of the page on scroll.

Comment: Just had to put absolute on header-cont